# regular expression for finding escaped apostrophe's around contractions

Tags: regex, sed

I have some text like this:

```
i18n_en_it_IT.xml:<li>risalire all&\#39;autore.</li>
```

and like this (note the escaped pound symbol in the first one but not in the second)

```
i18n_en_it_IT.xml:<li>risalire all&#39;autore.</li>
```

If I run a sed expression to replace the

```
&\#39; 
&#39;
```

with an oblique apostrophe (d\u2019) it works on the first case (with the escape), but not in the second, and I don't know why?  The only difference I see here is I remove the double escaping from the second one, but for some reason it won't match the all'autore and replace it with alld\u2019autore?

```
 s/\([A-Za-z]\+\)&\\#39;\([A-Za-z]\+\)/\1\\u2019\2/g
 s/\([A-Za-z]\+\)&#39;\([A-Za-z]\+\)/\1\\u2019\2/g
```

Comment: This is solved, the issue was I was adding a d\u2019 for the oblique apostrophe, when I removed it, both of these worked I've corrected the example to remove the d\u2019 and replace with just \u2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed -r`, which simplifies the masking, I can change both expressions if I follow the `\\` in `&\\#39;` with a `?`, to mark it as optional:

```
cat pounds.xml | sed -r 's/([A-Za-z]+)&\\?#39;([A-Za-z]+)/\1\\u2019\2/g'
```